# JRHtmlExporter is deprecated now 6.15.X jasper. How to define the IS_USING_IMAGES_TO_ALIGN?

Tags: jasper-reports

I replaced the usage of this class with JRHtmlExporter to HtmlExporter.

When I build my java file i got below error cannot find symbol IS_USING_IMAGES_TO_ALIGN

MY CODE IS:

```
exporter.setParameter(JRHtmlExporterParameter.IS_USING_IMAGES_TO_ALIGN, new Boolean("false"));
```

What is equivalent function?

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove this setting since it's not supported anymore (it's false by default), for more information see:

[How to set IS_USING_IMAGES_TO_ALIGN in HtmlExporter in Java ?](https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/1009991/how-set-isusingimagestoalign-htmlexporter-java) by [lucianc](https://community.jaspersoft.com/users/lucianc) staff of jasper-reports

> The new HtmlExporter does not support using images for alignment.  So you no longer need to set IS_USING_IMAGES_TO_ALIGN to false, it is false by default.